# Keeping flash on while Camera is open SwiftUI + UIImagePickerController

Tags: swiftui, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIViewControllerRepresentable struct as follows.

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    
    @Binding var didTapCapture: Bool
    
    @Binding var flash: Bool?
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        uiViewController.showsCameraControls = false
        if (didTapCapture == true){
                uiViewController.takePicture()
        
            
                didTapCapture = false
            }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePickerCoordinator {
        return ImagePickerCoordinator(isShown: $isShown, image: $image)
    }
    
    func toggleFlash() {
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else { return }
        guard device.hasTorch else { return }

        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()

            if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.on) {
                device.torchMode = AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.off
            } else {
                do {
                    try device.setTorchModeOn(level: 1.0)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        self.toggleFlash() // does not work
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.showsCameraControls = false
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

        return picker
    }
    
}
```

For reference, here is the corresponding ImagePickerCoordinator.

```
class ImagePickerCoordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    
    
    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    
    init(isShown: Binding<Bool>, image: Binding<UIImage?>) {
        _isShown = isShown
        _image = image
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        //self.toggleFlash()
        let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        image = uiImage
        isShown = false
        
    }
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        isShown = false
    }
    
}
```

When I open the camera, the flash briefly blinks on and then turns off when the camera view appears. I want to keep it on while the camera is showing. How can I do this with my current code?

Comment: `@Binding` only works in a `struct` that is a `SwiftUI.View` not in a `class`

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks for the feedback (I am new in using Swift). What should I change it to since the class initializes with a binding variable passed from another struct (which is a view). Also, would the Binding variables affect the flashlight?

Comment: you can leave it as a plain `var`. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) they will get you started. You are mixing 2 UI frameworks. There is a specific one on interfacing between the 2

Comment: Made the changes, but looks like the problem still persists